# ADFS - asynchronous requests

Tags: .net, ajax, servlets, request, adfs

I would like to ask if it is possible somehow to send asynchronous requests in ADFS adapter? Current state is, that I have an html page, I fill data and then press send, but the response does not come immediately, it takes a while, and for that period of time it is blocked. Is there a possibility to prevent this? I was thinking about some AJAX, but I read that it is not so easy. May be some of you have dealt with this problem? Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADFS is a "locked down" system for security reasons.

You can tinker around the margins with the look and feel of the pages but you have no real access to the authentication core.

Given that ADFS provides the claims which drive the user authorization for various pages and what functionality they have in each of them, you wouldn't be able to do much anyway while you wait.